# Why does this attempt to redefine the \selectlanguage fails?

Tags: macros

I tried to redefine `\selectlanguage` of `polyglossia` as follows:

```
\LetLtxMacro{\selectlanguage@original}{\selectlanguage}
\renewcommand{\selectlanguage}[2][]{\selectlanguage@original[#1]{#2}}
```

As I understood, this new `\selectlanguage` should behave exactly as before. However I keep getting errors

```
Package polyglossia: language * is not loaded. Please load it before using it..
```

How could I apply this redefinition properly, i.e. rebuild the `\selectlanguage` from `\selectlanguage@original`?

Below is a MWE.

```
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{french}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\selectlanguage@original}{\selectlanguage}
\renewcommand{\selectlanguage}[2][]{\selectlanguage@original[#1]{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french}
Text.

\selectlanguage{english}
Text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\selectlanguage` macro of `polyglossia` is defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` and using `\LetLtxMacro` will fail to do the proper job. Use `\NewCommandCopy` provided by the most recent LaTeX kernel.

Comment: \selectlanguage is defined with xparse, you can't  copy it with \LetLtxMacro. Why are you tring to redefine it?

Comment: The code works for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have removed support for the `*` form, with your redefinition

```
\selectlanguage * {english}
```

is

```
\selectlanguage@original[]{*}{english}
```

and leads to the error

```
! Package polyglossia Error: language * is not loaded. Please load it before us
ing it..

See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.2 \selectlanguage *
                     {english}
?
```